# Some basic questions about PFInstallation object in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server, pfinstallation

Im a bit confused how the [PFInstallation Object](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html) works in Parse

This much I understand:

> Every Parse application installed on a device registered for push
>   notifications has an associated PFInstallation object. The
>   PFInstallation object is where you store all the data needed to target
>   push notifications. Saving the PFInstallation object is also required
>   for tracking push-related app open events.

Here's where my confusion begins and I have tried to distill that in simple questions:

(Note I am not pushing by Channels. I am using "Advanced Targeting" where I determine a set of PFInstallation objects, associated with some target users and push to them)

1. When an app (that has an associated PFInstallation) is updated, what must happen for correct behavior to continue. The correct behavior here, is to continue receiving pushes. Does the code path, execute :

   installation.saveInBackground()

for an Object that is updated? (if nothing has changed only the updatedAt/modifiedAt should change, but it appears these are not tracked for the PFInstallation objects)

From what I understand, the above does nothing to the remote PFInstallation object, that is already available from the dashboard

2. When an app is deleted, does something need to happen to de-register/delete the remote instance of the PFinstallation, because it is now Invalid?
3. When an app is deleted and reinstalled and if 2 was not performed, the dashboard will now have duplicate instances of PFInstallations for that same device. Will the app now receive duplicate pushes? Or only a push to the most recent Installation object. If there are duplicate pushes, how do I eliminate those? If not, is it safe to delete duplicate instances of PFInstallation that are older than the most recent instance of that set?
4. In cloud code lets say I did the following:

   var q = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
               q.equalTo('userID', 'foo');

   ```
           Parse.Push.send({
             where: q,
             data: data
           }
   ```

Does this query guarantee that it will find me the "latest" Installation object where userID = foo, especially when multiple such objects exist?

Comment: saveInBackground will always save. it will update the modified date. 2) not required to be deleted i guess you can keep track of modified date to understand which users are not using the app. 3) after reinstallation , pretty sure you will get new token and it will replace that and the old token would be overwritten

Comment: Thanks! i have a follow up question. I edited the main post

Comment: it seems you did not edited it.

Comment: Just did - question 4

Comment: i would say you query the data and limit the result to be ordered by modified date and send to first result only.

Comment: ah ok, so no guarantees. So i need to do both a q.equalTo('userID', 'foo') and follow that up with a q.descending("createdAt") and get the [0] object if multiple exist, correct?

Comment: yup as per my thinking. you can still wait for a parse expert to reply although since the service is killed, not sure there will be many around.

Comment: @Shubhank saveinBackground try to save the object just oncem but if not success it wont try to save again - that is why we have saveEventually() .... 2. no, it will just leave the Row in the database and become useless 3. you will definetely get new token and the installation is stored in new row in DB. 4. As far as I know you need to add your own filed to target Specific user because the "native" PFInstallation class does not hold any information that is "targeting" the User in _User class

Comment: @MazelTov: Yes for 4, I do already have the association between PFInstallation and a User